# Version 320 is not supported, SDL C++

Tags: opengl, c++, shaders, sdl, macos

I have the following four lines before I create the window.

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
```

My shaders are of `#version 320 core` but I get these errors, the first from the vertex shader and the second from the fragment shader.

> ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '320' is not supported
>   ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
>   ERROR: 0:2: '' :  #version required and missing.
>   ERROR: 0:4: '0' : syntax error: integers in layouts require GLSL 140 or later
>
> ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '320' is not supported
>   ERROR: 0:1: '' : syntax error: #version
>   ERROR: 0:2: '' :  #version required and missing.

I am on OS X El Capitan but this setup worked before with Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia says that OpenGL 3.2 uses GLSL 1.50.11. Thus, you need to use `#version 150 core`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language

Comment: That does indeed solve the problem. Note that `150 core` still uses the old format but it does function perfectly well.